# emacs cedet semantic with Qt4 how to configure

Tags: emacs, emacs23, cedet

I use emacs 23.1.1 on X86_64-pc-gnu-linux (ubuntu 10.04) and follow the famous link http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html to add all config to .emacs.
But it can NOT do even basic job. There must be sth wrong with my setup or configue.

If I try to let it display the member function, it NOT be able to find.
[ auto complete use clang as parser. So what the parser semantic uses? ]

```
;; Load CEDET
(load-file "~/backup/cedet-trunk/common/cedet.el")
(global-ede-mode 1)                      
;(semantic-load-enable-code-helpers)       
(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)
;(semantic-load-enable-semantic-debugging-helpers)
(global-srecode-minor-mode 1)            
(global-semantic-tag-folding-mode 1)
(require 'semantic-tag-folding)
(global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode 1)
(global-semantic-idle-completions-mode 1)
(global-semantic-idle-summary-mode 1)
(global-semantic-idle-completions-mode)
(require 'semantic-ia)
(require 'eassist)
(require 'semantic-gcc)
(require 'semanticdb-global)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode)
(setq qt4-base-dir "/usr/include/qt4")
(setq qt4-gui-dir (concat qt4-base-dir "/QtGui"))
(setq qt4-core-dir (concat qt4-base-dir "/QtCore"))
(semantic-add-system-include qt4-base-dir 'c++-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include qt4-gui-dir 'c++-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include qt4-core-dir 'c++-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons qt4-base-dir 'c++-mode))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file (concat qt4-base-dir 
"/Qt/qconfig.h"))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file (concat qt4-base-dir "/Qt/qconfig-large.h"))
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file (concat qt4-base-dir "/Qt/qglobal.h"))

(defun my-cedet-hook ()
 (local-set-key [(control return)] 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu)
 (local-set-key "\C-c?" 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol)
 (local-set-key "\C-c>" 'semantic-complete-analyze-inline)
 (local-set-key "\C-c=" 'semantic-decoration-include-visit)
 (local-set-key "\C-cj" 'semantic-ia-fast-jump)
 (local-set-key "\C-cb" 'semantic-mrub-switch-tags)
 (local-set-key "\C-cd" 'semantic-ia-show-doc)
 (local-set-key "\C-cs" 'semantic-ia-show-summary)
 (local-set-key "\C-cp" 'semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle)
 (local-set-key "\C-cr" 'semantic-symref)
 (local-set-key "\C-c\-" 'senator-fold-tag)
 (local-set-key "\C-c\+" 'senator-unfold-tag)
 )

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'my-cedet-hook)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-cedet-hook)

(ede-cpp-root-project "Test"
        :name "Test Project"
        :file "~/project/shared/test-qt-semantic.cpp"
        :include-path '("/"
               )
        :system-include-path '("/usr/include/qt4"
                   "/usr/include/qt4/Qt"
                   "/usr/include/qt4/QtGui"
                   "/usr/include/qt4/QtCore"
                   ))
```

This is the source file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QString>
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
QApplication app (argc, argv);
QPushButton hello ("Hello, World!");
hello.resize (100, 30);
hello.show ();
QString id("hi");
return app.exec ();
}
```

> Unable to find datatype for: "class QPushButton hello ()".
>   Declared type is: "class QPushButton {}"
>   Raw data type is: ("QPushButton" type (:type "class") nil nil)
>
> Semantic could not find this data type in any of its global tables.
>
> Semantic locates datatypes through either the local scope, or the global
>   typecache.
>
> Local Scope Information:
>   * Tag Class Constraint against SCOPE: (type)
>   * No known parents in current scope.
>   * No known symbols currently in scope.
>   * No known symbols declared locally.
>   Semantic creates and maintains a type cache for each buffer.
>   If the type is a global type, then it should appear in they typecache.
>   To examine the typecache, type:
>
> M-x semanticdb-typecache-dump RET   [ Do It ]
>
> Current typecache Statistics:
>         0 types global in this file
>         0 types from includes.
>
> If the datatype is not in the typecache, then your include
>   path may be incorrect.
>
> Include Path Summary:
>
> This file's project include search is handled by the EDE object:
>     Buffer Target:  #ede-cpp-root-target /home/mike/project/shared/>
>     Buffer Project: #ede-cpp-root-project Test>
>     Backup Locator: #ede-locate-base Loc>
>
> The system include path is:
>
> ```
> /usr/include/qt4/
> /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/ 
> /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/x86_64-linux-gnu/
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/
> /usr/local/include/
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include-fixed/
> /usr/include/
> ```
>
> Include Summary: /home/mike/project/shared/test-qt-semantic.cpp
>
> test-qt-semantic.cpp contains 3 includes.
>      Unknown Includes:  0
>      Unparsed Includes: 0
>      Parsed Includes:   3
>    No unknown includes.

Comment: Given that they don't have a cedet-users mailing list, I would suggest trying [cedet-devel](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=cedet-devel) as well. (I am trying to get started on CEDET as well, it's been rough going thus far)

Answer (score 2):

Well at the bottom it says:

> It seems, that this approach will not work in fresh CEDET - I'm working on fix

and then in the comment he says:

> It seems, that CEDET wasn't compiled properly. Please, take CEDET from CVS and compile according instructions

So I think you should compile and build it again and then it should work - but I haven't tried that. I only suggest it because that's what the article said.